# Calculate the average of last X values in a row, but ignoring a set number of cells

Tags: excel, google-sheets, formula

I've been trying hard to solve this but haven't managed yet.

I have this sheet I'm using to keep track of my expenses on a monthly basis and every month I create a new column to register different types of expenses from that month. On each line, I have different expenses like groceries, entertainment, car, etc, and every month I add new values. The heather for each column has the month it corresponds to.

At the end of each line, after the last inserted monthly data, I also have some columns which I use to make calculations, such as total average and total value, so that I know how much I spend on each category. What I would like to do is to have another cell, at the end of each line, calculating the last 6 months average for each category (meaning, for each line)

[image: example of sheet structure]

As you can see in the image, every thin to the right of column AO is statistics. In column AR I would like to have a formula to calculate the last 6 month average, meaning it would look to the 6 months to the left of column AP (any cell with values) and do the average of those.

I would like this do be done without hardcoding "AP" column, since that changes every time I create the column for a new month. There is no problem though in hardcoding the number of statistics columns that are found at the end of each line (which are 5 in this example).

Any help is deeply appreciated

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Reversing the column order might solve your issue. Put the stats columns first, columns A-E, followed by the months, most recent first. You could then average columns G-L for the Last 6 Months column. Add a new column each month to the left of column G so the last 6 months is always columns G-L.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this: it selects all the row up to that cell (-1, that's why the OFFSET), reverses the order with that SEQUENCE and selects the 6 last cells that are not empty:

```
=AVERAGE(QUERY({TRANSPOSE($A3:OFFSET(AP3,0,-1)),SEQUENCE(COLUMN(AP3)-1)},"Select Col1 WHERE Col1 is not null order by Col2 desc Limit 6"))
```

As an array:

```
=BYROW($A3:OFFSET(AP3,0,-1),LAMBDA(each,AVERAGE(QUERY({TRANSPOSE(each),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(each))},"Select Col1 WHERE Col1 is not null order by Col2 desc Limit 6"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Maybe something like this?

leave only one input range for easy managment, the input range is set to be 1 column larger than the data, so whenever you insert new column, the range will enlarge by itself.

```
=LAMBDA(DATA,
 LAMBDA(DATA,
  LAMBDA(DATA,
   QUERY(BYROW(QUERY(DATA,"LIMIT "&COUNTA(INDEX(DATA,,1))-2,1),LAMBDA(ROW,IFERROR(AVERAGE(ROW),""))))
  )(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(DATA,"ORDER BY Col"&COUNTA(INDEX(DATA,1))&" DESC LIMIT 6",1)))
 )({DATA,{"Order";SEQUENCE(COUNTA(INDEX(DATA,,1))-1)}})
)(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({$A$2:$O},"WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL",1)),"WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL",1))
```